# Highlight mail in Outlook depending on appointment

Tags: outlook

I would like to highlight incoming mails if it's received during a certain appointment in the calendar.
To be more precise: everyone in our team is responsible for support on a weekly basis. I use my Outlook calendar to know when I'm responsible for support. Now I would like to hightlight incoming support mails if they arrive during this support appointment.

I doubt that it's possible to do this with Rules or Conditional Formatting. But: am I right? And if I'm right, perhaps there is an add-in? Or if not, could you give me a kickstart how I could write such a hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a rule on “Inbox” Folder.

First, you should make Important Email Standout in Outlook with Color Coding.

You could refer to this link:

[Make Important Email Standout in Outlook with Color Coding](https://www.techlicious.com/how-to/make-important-email-standout-in-outlook-with-color-coding1/)

When you select "Condition…", You should select “Advanced”

[image]

Click on FieId -> Frequently-used -> importance, “importance” select Low. Click on Add to List,  click “OK”

[image]

Second, you could create a Rule.

Click Rules -> create Rule, select “Advanced Options”

[image]

Select received in a specific data span, then selected your supported time periods.

[image]

Select make it as importance. Change high to Low

[image]

Finally, select “run this rule…” and “Turn on this rule” , click Finish.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! The question I'm really interested in: how to make the dates dynamic? I already enter the support times in the Calendar, I don't want to create a rule for each week I'm responsible for support. Yes, it would work. But would be great to let the rules use the Calendar.

Comment: You could create a macro rule, use vba to get Calendar appointment. Then use vba to set "Inbox" Folder email to high importance. You could refer to these links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/search-the-calendar-for-appointments-within-a-date-range-that-contain-a-specific  http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?60033-Excel-vba-set-email-on-outlook-to-high-importance

Comment: It seems that I'm not able to use macro rules in Outlook 365/2016 (didn't try, but I read this wasn't possible). So I started to write a macro which is executed for each incoming mail. And I stumble upon the 80/20 rule, 80% of the macro were pretty easy. I have a `WithEvents` variable on the items of the default inbox folder. And a listener `inboxItems_ItemAdd`. The last 20% is to set the mail's importance:
`Item.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceHigh`
doesn't change anything on the mail item in my inbox. Replacing this line by a MsgBox statement brings up the MsgBox.

Comment: You could use this code "Dim Filter As String
        Filter = "[Importance] = 2"

    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)" ,  Please refer to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665683/outlook-count-emails-mark-as-important

Comment: This would give me mail items with high importance. What I want to do is to set the importance of the received mail in my inbox to high. But `item.Importance = olImportanceHigh` doesn't change the importance/priority of the corresponding mail in my inbox.

Comment: You could get Calendar item, then get your support time period. According to this , You could change your Inbox email importance in this time period. According to my test, this code:"Dim Filter As String Filter = "[Importance] = 2" Dim Items As Outlook.Items Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)" can change mail importance

Comment: Somehow I got on the right track, what I just needed to do was to save the change.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I didn't test if the following code works if I'm currently not responsible for support. I'll check this on Monday :) And the `isSupportDay` function still needs some refactoring.

```
Option Explicit    

Private WithEvents inboxItems As Outlook.Items    
Private isTodaySupport As Boolean    

Private Sub Application_Startup()    
    isTodaySupport = isSupportDay()    

    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application    
    Dim objectNS As Outlook.NameSpace    

    Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application    
    Set objectNS = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")    
    Set inboxItems = objectNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items    
End Sub    

Private Sub inboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler    

    If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" And isTodaySupport And isSupportMail(Item) Then    
        Item.Importance = OlImportance.olImportanceHigh    
        'Item.MarkAsTask (OlMarkInterval.olMarkToday)    
        Item.Save    
    End If    

    ExitNewItem:    
        Exit Sub    

    ErrorHandler:    
        MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description    
        Resume ExitNewItem    
End Sub    

Function isSupportDay() As Boolean    
    Dim myStart As Date    
    Dim myEnd As Date    
    Dim oCalendar As Outlook.Folder    
    Dim oItems As Outlook.Items    
    Dim oItemsInDateRange As Outlook.Items    
    Dim oFinalItems As Outlook.Items    
    Dim oAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem    
    Dim strRestriction As String    

    myStart = Date    
    myEnd = DateAdd("h", 1, myStart)    

    'Construct filter    
    strRestriction = "[Start] >= '" & _    
        Format$(myStart, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM") _    
        & "' AND [End] <= '" & _    
        Format$(myEnd, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AMPM") & "'"    

    Set oCalendar = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)    
    Set oItems = oCalendar.Items    
    oItems.IncludeRecurrences = True    
    oItems.Sort "[Start]"    

    'Restrict the Items collection for the date range    
    Set oItemsInDateRange = oItems.Restrict(strRestriction)    

    'Construct filter for Subject containing 'team'    
    Const PropTag  As String = "https://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/"    
    strRestriction = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & PropTag _    
        & "0x0037001E" & Chr(34) & " = 'Support'"    

    'Restrict the last set of filtered items for the subject    
    Set oFinalItems = oItemsInDateRange.Restrict(strRestriction)    

    isSupportDay = oFinalItems.Count > 0    
End Function    

Function isSupportMail(Item As Outlook.mailItem) As Boolean    
    isSupportMail = Item.Subject Like "Support - (*"    
End Function
```